# Calling WinBUGS14 from R

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs

I'm trying to call WinBUGS from R, but I have not been very successful.

I typed this code in R:

```
radon.data <- list ("n", "J", "x", "y", "county")
radon.inits <- function (){
  list (a=rnorm(J), b=rnorm(1), mu.a=rnorm(1),
        sigma.y=runif(1), sigma.a=runif(1))
}
radon.parameters <- c ("a", "b", "mu.a", "sigma.y", "sigma.a")
```

Then, I call WinBUGS:

```
radon.bugs.1 <- bugs (radon.data, radon.inits, radon.parameters, "radon.1.bug", n.iter=10,
        bugs.directory="C:/Program Files/WinBUGS14", working.directory=NULL, clearWD=TRUE, debug=TRUE )
```

And I get following error in the WinBUGS:

```
set(sigma.y)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(sigma.a)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
set(deviance)
command #Bugs:set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
dic.set()
command #Bugs:dic.set cannot be executed (is greyed out)
update(5)
command #Bugs:update cannot be executed (is greyed out)
coda(*,C:/Users/Gabriel/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpf1rAQa/coda)
command #Bugs:coda cannot be executed (is greyed out)
stats(*)
command #Bugs:stats cannot be executed (is greyed out)
dic.stats()

DIC
history(*,C:/Users/Gabriel/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpf1rAQa/history.odc)
command #Bugs:history cannot be executed (is greyed out)
save(C:/Users/Gabriel/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpf1rAQa/log.odc)
save(C:/Users/Gabriel/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpf1rAQa/log.txt)
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me. My files are in the same

Comment: what is the content of your file radon.1.bug? This will be the key of problems, I think.

Answer (score 2):

These error messages occur when your bug has not compiled. Try working in WinBUGS first, until you can get the model up and running. Then save the

```
model{
    ....
    bayesian model
    ....
}
```

part as the .bug file.